# How can I pass login_hint/authuser to Google IdP when using AWS SSO

Tags: amazon-web-services, google, single-sign-on, identity-management

I have configured AWS SSO to use Google as an IdP. It's working fine.

However, since I have multiple google accounts I often have to go through the multiple login 'chooser'.

When accessing Google services I can use a bookmark/URL like this to jump past the multiple login page

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=user@domain1.com
https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=an-other-user@domain1.com
https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=user@domain2.com
```

Is there an equivalent for AWS SSO start url?

e.g.

In `.aws/config` I have something like this:

```
[profile admin]
sso_start_url = https://XXXXX.awsapps.com/start
sso_account_id = XXXXX
sso_role_name = AdministratorAccess
```

What can I add to the `sso_start_url` such that it is passed to Google IdP during the SSO handshake, each aws account is associated with a single google identity, so I will never need to choose google account for a given aws cli profile.

I've tried

```
# This has no effect
sso_start_url = https://XXXXX.awsapps.com/start?authuser=user@domain1.com

# OIDC seems to support login_hint, but this has no effect
sso_start_url = https://XXXXX.awsapps.com/start?login_hint=user@domain1.com
```

Perhaps some configuration is required on the AWS or Google end to support this?